# Firestore Index Rules format JSON

Tags: json, firebase, visual-studio-code, google-cloud-firestore

I'm relatively new to Firebase and Firestore, I have created 2 Index in the firestore web app and seems like I also have to update the firestore.indexes.json on my IDE.

[image]

Base from the image above, is this the correct way of adding it on VSCODE? I'm just assuming it is.

```
{
  "indexes": [
    {
      "collectionGroup": "timeinout",
      "queryScope": "COLLECTION",
      "fields": [
        {
          "fieldPath": "uid",
          "order": "ASCENDING"
        },
        {
          "fieldPath": "createdAt",
          "order": "ASCENDING"
        },
        {
          "fieldPath": "uid",
          "order": "ASCENDING"
        },
        {
          "fieldPath": "timein",
          "order": "ASCENDING"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "fieldOverrides": []
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The index definition is almost there, but it will only create one index, across all four of those fields (one of which, uid, will be duplicated).

To create 2 indexes, you can put 2 entries in the `indexes` array rather than putting all 4 fields into a single index entry:

```
{
  "indexes": [
    {
      "collectionGroup": "timeinout",
      "queryScope": "COLLECTION",
      "fields": [
        {
          "fieldPath": "uid",
          "order": "ASCENDING"
        },
        {
          "fieldPath": "createdAt",
          "order": "ASCENDING"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "collectionGroup": "timeinout",
      "queryScope": "COLLECTION",
      "fields": [
        {
          "fieldPath": "uid",
          "order": "ASCENDING"
        },
        {
          "fieldPath": "timein",
          "order": "ASCENDING"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "fieldOverrides": []
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to export that JSON from the Firestore console?